# Workflow for quickly building something with a specific non-standard build option

Tags: build-pipeline, builds, workflow

Suppose you need to build something with a specific non-standard build option. So far, my workflow for dealing with this has been: First, check if there's a gentoo package with the USE flag you need, and make a Gentoo container with it. If this isn't possible, make a nix flake that modifies an existing nix package, e.g., using `overrideAttrs`. And if that doesn't work, you have to just freestyle until you figure out the proper dependencies/dev tools to make the build. Is there any other way to go about this?